# ScrollView in custom Static Cell not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a static tableView in which one of the cells is a custom cell with a scrollview and pageControl to show images, similar like a slideshow, paginated.

For that, I created the Custom Table view cell as below. I can see the first image when I run the simulator and also the paginationControl but the horizontal scrollview doesn't work. I can't find a way to make scrollview to work in it. Is it because it's a static cell? Or I'm missing something?

```
class AdImageViewerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var adImagesScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var adImagesPageControl: UIPageControl!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.configureImagePageControl()
    self.adImagesScrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

    adImagesScrollView.delegate = self

    // test purposes
    for index in 0...3 {

        var frame = CGRect.zero
        frame.origin.x = self.adImagesScrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
        frame.origin.y = 0
        frame.size = self.adImagesScrollView.frame.size


        let myImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
        // test
        myImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:"https://images-americanas.b2w.io/produtos/01/00/item/123402/7/123402763SZ.jpg"))

        myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        myImageView.frame = frame

        self.adImagesScrollView.addSubview(myImageView)
        self.addSubview(self.adImagesPageControl)
    }

    self.adImagesScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.adImagesScrollView.frame.size.width, height: self.adImagesScrollView.frame.size.height)
    self.adImagesPageControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("changePage:")), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

}

func configureImagePageControl() {
    // The total number of pages that are available is based on how many available colors we have.
    self.adImagesPageControl.layer.zPosition = 1

    self.adImagesPageControl.numberOfPages = 4
    //self.adImagesPageControl.numberOfPages = (ad.adImages?.count)!
    self.adImagesPageControl.currentPage = 0
    self.adImagesPageControl.tintColor = UIColor.red
    self.adImagesPageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
    self.adImagesPageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.green
    self.addSubview(adImagesPageControl)
}



override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let pageWidth:CGFloat = scrollView.frame.width
    let currentPage:CGFloat = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1
    self.adImagesPageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage)

}

func changePage(sender: AnyObject) -> () {
    let x = CGFloat(adImagesPageControl.currentPage) * adImagesScrollView.frame.size.width
    adImagesScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: x,y :0), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: First off, you're likely to have some issues embedding scrollable elements inside scrollable elements, though sometimes that's just the requirement of the designer.  You are setting the contentSize of the scrollView to be the same size as the frame of the scrollView, which means there's nothing to scroll. You need it to have content wider than the frame for scrolling to work.

Comment: Ah, @creeperspeak, you are right (two times actually :D), it's a design requirement and the contentSize is indeed the root of the "problem". I spent some hours trying to figure out what was going on and you in 10 minutes solved the problem! Thank you very, very much.